# How to use time zone info class in .Net with oracle for time zone conversion

Tags: .net, oracle

I wish to use Timezone Info class of .Net  and display it in a drop down.
When user selects any time zone that needs to pass to oracle query and i am using from_tz.
Previously i use to pass time zones in a format 'America/New_York' and it seems to work fine in oracle but now i need to pass on data from timezone info class which will be 'Eastern Standard Time' but not this doesn't work in oracle as it throws error "Time zone region not found " i believe the format doesn't support by oracle.
Is there a way to accomplish this implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must call it `US/Eastern`.

This query returns all time zones available in Oracle:

```
SELECT tzabbrev, tzname, TZ_OFFSET(tzname) FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES;
```

Note, you must use `tzname` values , not `tzabbrev` (unless the are equal)

Comment: I used in previously but now i need to use more generalized and shorter list so i thought of using .Net Time zone list but then how do i get it to work with Oracle